# Javascript Dynamic Json object based up on the input numbers

Tags: javascript

I am getting two different integer from the user:

I have one set of Key & Value pair Json object as follows,

```
{
    red : 250,
    yellow : 160,
    green : 140,
    showName : "Power Terminal Water Temperature (°F)",
    displayName : "WaterTemperature-Z",
    value : 0
}
```

Based up on the input i have to create the dynamic json object. Consider the

input 1: 2 and
input 2: 2, then I have to create the Json like

```
{
    red : 250,
    yellow : 160,
    green : 140,
    showName : "Power Terminal 1 Water Temperature (°F)",
    displayName : "WaterTemperature-Z1",
    value : 0
},
{
    red : 250,
    yellow : 160,
    green : 140,
    showName : "Power Terminal 2 Water Temperature (°F)",
    displayName : "WaterTemperature-Z1_1",
    value : 1
},
{
    red : 250,
    yellow : 160,
    green : 140,
    showName : "Power Terminal 3 Water Temperature (°F)",
    displayName : "WaterTemperature-Z2",
    value : 2
},
{
    red : 250,
    yellow : 160,
    green : 140,
    showName : "Power Terminal 4 Water Temperature (°F)",
    displayName : "WaterTemperature-Z2_2",
    value : 3
}
```

I need to populate the json like this as per the user's input.

Can you assist me - I am new to JavaScript

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post code and effort. Visit the [help] to see why

Answer (score 0):

Look for `.extend()` method in popular JS libraries like `underscore` or `jQuery`, or, if you have a new JS runtime, you should have `Object.assign` method.

Alternatively do it in pure JS:

```
var obj = {
    red : 250,
    yellow : 160,
    green : 140,
    showName : "Power Terminal Water Temperature (°F)",
    displayName : "WaterTemperature-Z",
    value : 0
};

var obj2 = {};
for(var prop in obj) {
    obj2[prop] = obj[prop];
}
```